# Symfony 3 and nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have SF3 application which runs fine on apache2 but when I use nginx http://localhost/SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/app_dev.php runs also fine producing a start page. When I try  to get any other route like /api nginx gives me 404. It seems that nginx with my configuration doesn't  like pretty routes at all.  It looks for /api directory

2017/04/24 21:51:42 [error] 23683#23683: *2 open() "/var/www/html/SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/app_dev.php/api" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/app_dev.php/api HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Why is it? And what should I do?

listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

```
# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;


 location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus
    # for more information).
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections 768;
   # multi_accept on;
}

 http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json                            application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss      text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this guide? http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Comment: It is exactly what I  did.

Comment: It is only problem with sf as my others wp apps work under nginx

Comment: Is it nginx's 404 error page or Symfony's? If it's nginx's, please post it's configuration. Maybe you have some kind of typo there.

Comment: It seems nginx's 404 error page as I put some dump in app_dev.php. It works well with the start page and doesnt work with 404.

Comment: That means that url rewriting is not working correctly. nginx config would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks I am new to nginx and It seems that I dont have any url rewritings

Comment: You've pasted some of nginx config, but the important part is somewhere on the top. What's the value of `root` option?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong with root?

Answer (score 0):

```
Symfony doc gives us  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

But in Ubuntu 16.04 it should be fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5-fpm.sock. That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Symfony's doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx), `root` should point to `web` directory.

I guess, that `/var/www/html` is your whole localhost server root and you may be unable to change it, because you have other projects there and you would loose access to them.

Without changing this `root` value, you have two options.

First one is to **fix `location` sections** so instead of:

location ~ ^/(app_dev|config).php(/|$) {

it should be something like:

```
location ~ ^/{path_relative_to_root}/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
```

Basing on the information that you tried url `http://localhost/SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/app_dev.php`, this path is probably `/SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/`, so it should be:

```
location ~ ^/SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
```

Second is to **create separate virtual host for this project**, so it could have completely separate domain (e.g. symfonyapp.local or any else).

To do that you should create separate config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` which content similar similar to that shown in example form Symfony's doc. Just need to change root path and domain name. And of course you need to enable this nginx site by making a symbolik link in `sites_enabled`.

Then you also need to add this domain to `hosts` file in your OS.

In this case you will be able to access your site with simple `http://symfonyapp.local/app_dev.php`.

Comment: Thank you, but with location ~ ^/SF3-REST-USER-JWT/web/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) it gives me 502 Bad Gateway even in the first case now

Comment: I don't know you **exact** server configuration so I can't give you 100% ready solution.